# MySQL Query error using UNION/UNION ALL and Group By

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Generate the following two result sets:

**1).** Query an alphabetically ordered list of all names in OCCUPATIONS, immediately followed by the first letter of each profession as a parenthetical (i.e.: enclosed in parentheses). For example: AnActorName(A), ADoctorName(D), AProfessorName(P), and ASingerName(S).

**2).** Query the number of ocurrences of each occupation in OCCUPATIONS. Sort the occurrences in ascending order, and output them in the following format:

`There are total [occupation_count] [occupation]s.`

Table Name: Occupations

Total Columns: Two = 'Name' and 'Occupation', demo table is shown below:

[image: Table: Occupations]

**Sample Output:**

```
Ashely(P)
Christeen(P)
Jane(A)
Jenny(D)
Julia(A)
Ketty(P)
Maria(A)
Meera(S)
Priya(S)
Samantha(D)
There are total 2 doctors.
There are total 2 singers.
There are total 3 actors.
There are total 3 professors.
```

**My Approach:**

```
(SELECT NAME, '(', SUBSTRING(OCCUPATION, 1, 1), ')' 
    FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY NAME) 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY OCCUPATION ORDER BY ASEC);
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR 1222 (21000) at line 1: 
    The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns
```

Thank You!

Comment: For all answerers: PLEASE DO NOT JUST POST A BLOCK OF CODE AS AN ANSWER!!! You need to explain what the code does, how it does it, and how it is different from the OP's statement. Code-only answers are not acceptable in Stack Overflow.

Comment: For all that want to add an answer to this question. First look on all other answers, and see if you **REALLY** have a new approach. As most answers are just copied from other and added small minor changes which doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes on HackerRank concat functon will give an error. You can use || to seperate in the same way.

So if the code below doesnt work for you:

```
(
  SELECT CONCAT(NAME, '(', SUBSTRING(OCCUPATION, 1, 1), ')') as THETEXT, '1' as SELECTNUMBER
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
)
UNION ALL 
(
  SELECT CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(*),' ', OCCUPATION, (IF (COUNT(*) > 1, 's',''))) as THETEXT, '2' as SELECTNUMBER
   FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY OCCUPATION
)
ORDER BY SELECTNUMBER ASC, THETEXT ASC;
```

TRY THIS INSTEAD!

SELECT name || '(' || UPPER(SUBSTR(occupation, 1, 1)) || ')' FROM occupations ORDER BY name;

SELECT 'There are a total of' || ' ' || COUNT(occupation) || ' ' || LOWER(occupation) || 's' || '.' FROM occupations GROUP BY occupation ORDER BY COUNT(occupation) ASC;

Comment: Actually i tried that, but still one issue. I am getting output(no errors now), but not as desired. **Output :** `There are total 4actors.` You can see the `4` is sticked to `actors.`

Comment: It seems odd, because this part of code `CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(*),' ', OCCUPATION,'s')` definitely add space between number and occupation.

Comment: Yes, it works the space but still not ordered in ascending.

Comment: I add some data to sqlfiddle example to demonstrate that ordering in second select in ascending order.

Comment: Sorry but am not getting the results. Try here please, https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-pads

Comment: Issue is order for names and count does not work their.

Comment: You haven't added info about `The results of the second query are ascendingly ordered first by number of names corresponding to each profession (2≤2≤3≤32≤2≤3≤3), and then alphabetically by profession`. So now I've added second sorting to query. Also I've changed sqlfiddle example to show that it works.

Comment: Sorry for that, but still this is what i get. Even for the first query order doesnot work. Check this: http://i.imgur.com/2DJT0eR.png

Comment: Yes, I forgot to move `order by` to the end of query. See new query and new link to sqlfiddle

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work for me. There is no need of numbers 1 and 2 in the output. Also, as there is a needy to apply order to both SELECT statements its better not use UNION. Use `;` to separate the SELECT statements instead.

Answer (score 5):

I just tried on hackerrank and it works, You don't need to use Union.

```
select concat(name,'(',upper(substring(occupation,1,1)),')') from occupations
order by name;

select concat("There are a total of",' ',count(occupation),' ',lower(occupation),'s',".")  from occupations
group by occupation
order by count(occupation) asc;
```

EDIT using UNION to remove the extra line :

```
SELECT CONCAT(NAME, '(' , LEFT(OCCUPATION, 1), ')')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
UNION

SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ', ' ', COUNT(OCCUPATION), ' ', LOWER(OCCUPATION), 's.')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION;
```

Comment: What does the `upper` do ?

Comment: ok I understand! its for caps or non-caps letters

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT concat(NAME,concat("(",LEFT(occupation,1),")")) 
FROM OCCUPATIONS 
ORDER BY NAME ASC;

select CONCAT("There are a total of", " ",COUNT(occupation), " ",LCASE(occupation),"s",".")AS stat
from OCCUPATIONS
group by occupation
order by COUNT(occupation) ASC,occupation
```

Comment: It would be better if you explain why your code would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
(
  SELECT CONCAT(NAME, '(', SUBSTRING(OCCUPATION, 1, 1), ')') as THETEXT
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
)
UNION ALL 
(
  SELECT CONCAT('There are total ', COUNT(*),' ', LOWER(OCCUPATION) ,(IF (COUNT(*) > 1, 's','')), '.') as THETEXT
   FROM OCCUPATIONS  group by  OCCUPATION
)
ORDER by THETEXT ASC;
```

Answer (score 1):

Worked on hackerrank

```
SELECT Name || '(' || SUBSTR(Occupation,1,1) || ')'-- AS THETEXT, '1' AS SELECTNUMBER
    FROM OCCUPATIONS
    order by Name;

    SELECT 'There are a total of' || ' ' || COUNT(*) || ' ' || lower(Occupation) || 's.'
    FROM OCCUPATIONS  GROUP BY OCCUPATION                            
    ORDER BY COUNT(Occupation), lower(Occupation);
```

Comment: Throws an error, did you check properly. I think it works in DB2

Answer (score 0):

union requires the two queries have the same number of columns, you can add any some columns to the second query to make them like the first one like SELECT COUNT(*), 'col-1', 'col-2', 'col-3' from

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on MySQL

```
select concat(name,"(",substr(occupation,1,1),")") from occupations
order by name asc;

select concat('There are total ',count(*),' ',lower(occupation),'s.') as n from occupations
group by occupation
order by n asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(name,'(',left(occupation,1),')') from occupations order by name;


select concat('There are total of',' ',count(occupation),' ',lower(occupation),"s.") from occupations group by occupation order by count(occupation),occupation;
```

Comment: Please provide an explanation in [all] your answers.  Please see: [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

```
(Select name||'('||substr(Occupation,0,1)||')'  
from OCCUPATIONS)
Union All
(Select 'There are a total of '||count(*)||' '||lower(Occupation)||'s.'  
from OCCUPATIONS group by Occupation) 
order by 1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(name, '(', SUBSTRING(occupation, 1, 1), ')') as occ from occupations ORDER BY name;

SELECT concat('There are a total of ', COUNT(*), ' ', LCASE(occupation),  's.') from occupations GROUP BY occupation ORDER BY COUNT(*), occupation;
```

This does the charm.

Comment: s. should be dynamic. In above statement it is hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT CONCAT(NAME ,'('||SUBSTR(occupation,1,1)||')')
      FROM occupations 
  ORDER BY NAME ASC;

    SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ',COUNT (occupation)||' '||LOWER(occupation)||'s.')
      FROM occupations 
  GROUP BY occupation 
  ORDER BY COUNT(occupation),occupation ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
select CONCAT(name,'(',left(occupation,1),')') 
from OCCUPATIONS 
order by name;

select CONCAT('There are a total of',' ',count(occupation),' ',lower(occupation),'s.') 
from OCCUPATIONS 
group by occupation 
order by count(occupation), occupation;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(NAME,'(',LEFT(OCCUPATION,1),')')
FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY NAME;

SELECT CONCAT("There are total of ",COUNT_OCCUPATION," ",OCCUPATION,".")
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(OCCUPATION) AS COUNT_OCCUPATION,OCCUPATION
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT_OCCUPATION ASC,OCCUPATION ASC) AS OCP
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONCAT(NAME, '(', left(OCCUPATION,1),')') from OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY NAME;

select CONCAT("There are a total of ", count(OCCUPATION), " ", lower(OCCUPATION),(if(count(OCCUPATION) >1,"s","")), ".") from OCCUPATIONS group by occupation order by count(OCCUPATION), OCCUPATION;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(name, '(',substring(occupation,1,1),')') from OCCUPATIONS order  by name;
select concat('There are a total of ',count(occupation),' ',lower(occupation),'s.') as 'sentence' from OCCUPATIONS group by occupation order by count(occupation), occupation,field(occupation,'doctor','singer','actor','professor');
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

check below code. hope this helps its 100% working

```sql
select concat(Name,"(",left(Occupation,1),")")
  from occupations 
 order by Name;

select concat("There are a total of ",count(Occupation),' ',lower(occupation),"s.") 
  from Occupations
 group by occupation 
 order by count(Occupation)asc, Occupation;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  /* sort answer is here */ 
     ( select concat(name,'(',left(occupation,1),')') as ocps from 
      Occupations) union 
     (select distinct concat('There are a total of 
     ',count(occupation),' ',lower(occupation),'s.') from Occupations 
     group by occupation)order by ocps;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select Name+'('+substring(Occupation,1,1)+')' from occupations order by name asc;

select concat('There are a total of',' ', count(occupation),' ',Lower(occupation),'s','.') from Occupations group by Occupation order by count(occupation), occupation asc
```

Answer (score 0):

One can make use of the UNION operator in MySQL to union each part of the question.

**NOTE:** To combine the column names into one column the `CONCAT()` function can be used.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(name, '(', left(occupation, 1), ')') AS n
from OCCUPATIONS
union
select concat('There are a total of ', (select count(*) from OCCUPATIONS group by occupation having occupation = 'doctor'), ' doctors.')
union
select concat('There are a total of ', (select count(*) from OCCUPATIONS group by occupation having occupation = 'singer'), ' singers.')
union
select concat('There are a total of ', (select count(*) from OCCUPATIONS group by occupation having occupation = 'actor'), ' actors.')
union
select concat('There are a total of ', (select count(*) from OCCUPATIONS group by occupation having occupation = 'professor'), ' professors.')

order by n asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(Name,'(',substring(Occupation,1,1),')') from OCCUPATIONS order by Name;

select 
concat('There are a total of ',count(*),' ',LCASE(Occupation),
       If(count(*)>1,'s.','')) 
       from OCCUPATIONS group by Occupation order by count(*) ASC
       ;
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it; never just post code on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code for Mysql. This works best for me. I have tried and got the correct results.

```
select concat(name,'(',left(occupation,1),')') from occupations
order by name;

select concat('There are a total of ',count,' ',lower(occupation),'s.') from (select occupation, count(*) as count from occupations group by occupation)a

order by count, occupation;
```

1. For first query, I have concat the column 'name' with brackets and 1st char of value in column occupation. later order by is arranging them in ascending order (by default it is in ascending order).
2. second query, order by count(occupation) was not working for me so to solve this, i have used nested queries. Query in bracket is providing me occupation column, count of occupation when it is group by. then i concat the string with count and occupation name. later order by count in ascending order. Further if count is same for 2 occupations , so used order by occupation too to arrange them in ascending order.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat(name,'(',left(occupation,1),')')
FROM occupations
ORDER BY name;
```

```
SELECT concat('There are a total of ',cnt,' ',lower(occupation),'s.') FROM (
  SELECT occupation,count(occupation) as cnt
  FROM occupations
  GROUP BY occupation
) a
ORDER BY cnt,occupation;
```

Comment: I suggest  you to more explain your answer: why this should fix the issue ? what did you change ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this way:

```
 SELECT CONCAT(NAME,"(",SUBSTRING(Occupation, 1, 1),")") FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY NAME
    SELECT CONCAT("There are a total of"," ",COUNT(Occupation),
    " ",LOWER(Occupation),"s",".") FROM OCCUPATIONS GROUP BY Occupation ORDER BY COUNT(Occupation),Occupation
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too, no need of union as they are asking for 2 separate queries

```
select name||'('||substr(occupation,1,1)||')' from occupations order by name;

select 'There are a total of ',cnt,decode(occ,'P','professors','D','doctors',
'S','singers','A','actors')||'.'
from
(select distinct(substr(occupation,1,1)) as occ,count(*) as cnt from occupations group by substr(occupation,1,1)) order by cnt,occ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(name,"(",substring(occupation, 1, 1), ")") from occupations order by name;

select concat("There are a total of ", count(Occupation), " ", lower(occupation), "s.") from occupations group by occupation order by count(Occupation), Occupation;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(Name,'(',upper(substr(Occupation,1,1)),')') from OCCUPATIONS order by Name;
select concat('There are a total of',' ',count(Occupation),' ',lower(Occupation),'s','.') from OCCUPATIONS group by Occupation order by count(Occupation) asc,lower(Occupation);
```

P.S--- LOOK AT THE SECOND QUERY...*ADD A FULLSTOP*

Comment: What does this add/do that the other 40 answers don't?

Answer (score 0):

This works on Hacker rank, check this out

```
(select concat(name,'(',substr(occupation,1,1),')') N
from OCCUPATIONS) 
union
(select concat('There are a total of ',count(occupation),' ',lower(occupation),'s.') from 
occupations
group by occupation)
order by N asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH t1 AS (SELECT name, 
             LEFT(occupation,1) AS firstletter
             FROM occupations
             ORDER BY 1)
                              
SELECT CONCAT(name, '(', firstletter, ')') AS result
FROM t1;

WITH t2 AS (SELECT occupation,
            COUNT(occupation) AS occupation_count 
            FROM occupations
            GROUP BY 1
            ORDER BY 2,1)

SELECT CONCAT('There ','are ','a ','total ','of ',occupation_count,' ' ,LOWER(occupation),'s','.') 
FROM t2;
```

I have broken the question down into two CTE(Common table expression) which are temporary tables. The first CTE(t1) selects the occupation table for name, selects the first letter of the data in occupation column using "LEFT()" function then orders alphabetically by name as required by the question. The select statement then queries the CTE(t1) using "CONCAT()" function to obtain its result.
CTE(t2)  selects occupation, "COUNT()", group by occupation and order by occupation count and occupation. the select statement then queries t2 using "CONCAT()"

Comment: *`CONCAT('There ','are ','a ','total ','of '`* - er... You're allowed to write more than one word in a string..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT(NAME,"(",LEFT(OCCUPATION,1),")") FROM OCCUPATIONS
ORDER BY NAME;

SELECT CONCAT("There are a total of ",COUNT(OCCUPATION)," ",lower(OCCUPATION),"s.")
FROM OCCUPATIONS
GROUP BY OCCUPATION
ORDER BY COUNT(OCCUPATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

select concat(name,'(',upper(left(occupation,1)),')') as name
from occupations
order by name;

select concat('There are a total of ',count(*),' ',lower(occupation),'s.')
from occupations
group by occupation
order by count(*)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(name,"(",substr(occupation,1,1),")") as name from occupations
union all
select concat("There are a total of ",count(occupation)," ",lower(occupation),"s.") as descriptions from occupations group by 
occupation order by name
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select distinct Name + '('+left(Occupation,1)+')'as a
    from OCCUPATIONS 
    union
    select  ('There are total ' +cast( count( Occupation) as nvarchar) + ' '+ lower(Occupation) +'s.') as b 
    from OCCUPATIONS
    GROUP BY OCCUPATION
    ) AS N
ORDER BY a
```

This works for me on MS SQL Server.

Answer (score -1):

```
//Just be careful for the format!

(select concat(name, '(',left(occupation,1),')') as text
from occupations
)
union all
(
   select concat(
       'There are total ', 
       count(*), ' ', lower(occupation), 
       case
        when COUNT(*) > 1 
        then 's'
       end
       ,
       '.'
    ) as text
    from occupations
    group by occupation
)
order by text asc;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select 
  case when Occupation='Doctor' then concat(concat(concat(Name,'('),'D'),')') 
       when Occupation='Actor' then concat(concat(concat(Name,'('),'A'),')') 
       when Occupation='Professor' then concat(concat(concat(Name,'('),'P'),')')
       when Occupation='Singer' then concat(concat(concat(Name,'('),'S'),')')end as name
from OCCUPATIONS
order by name asc;

select concat(concat(concat(concat('There are a total of ',count(Occupation)),' '),lower(Occupation)),'s.')
from OCCUPATIONS
group by Occupation
order by Count(Occupation) asc,lower(Occupation);
```

Comment: please do a proper formatting for your answer, e.g. format the code sections.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score -2):

```
select (name||'('||UPPER(substr(occupation,1,1))||')') from occupations order by name;

select ('There are a total of '||count(name)||' '||lower(occupation)||'s.') from occupations group by occupation order by count(name), occupation;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select distinct Name + '('+left(Occupation,1)+')'as a
    from OCCUPATIONS 
    union
    select  ('There are total ' +cast( count( Occupation) as nvarchar) + ' '+ lower(Occupation) +'s.') as b 
    from OCCUPATIONS
    GROUP BY OCCUPATION
    ) AS N
ORDER BY a
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score -2):

```sql
(select concat(name , '(' , left(OCCUPATION , 1) , ')' ) as text  from OCCUPATIONS order by name asc ) 
union all
( 
    select concat('There are a total of ' , (select count(occupation) from OCCUPATIONS where occupation = 'Doctor') , ' doctors' , "." )
) 
union all
( 
    select concat('There are a total of ' , (select count(occupation) from OCCUPATIONS where occupation = 'Singer ') , ' singers', "."  ) 
) 
union all 
(
    select concat('There are a total of ' , (select count(occupation) from OCCUPATIONS where occupation = 'Actor') , ' actors'  , ".")  
) 
union all 
( 
    select concat('There are a total of ' , (select count(occupation) from OCCUPATIONS where occupation = 'Professor') , ' professors' , "."  )
) 
order by text asc;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
select Name + '('+ substring(OCCUPATION, 1,1) +')' from OCCUPATIONS 
union  
select 'There are total ' + cast(count(OCCUPATION) as varchar) +' '+ 
lower(OCCUPATION)+'s.' from OCCUPATIONS   
group by OCCUPATION
```

Comment: Please explain your answer and then please take time for formatting

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -3):

```
SELECT CONCAT (NAME, CONCAT ('(',LEFT(OCCUPATION,1),')'))FROM OCCUPATIONS ORDER BY NAME ASC;

SELECT CONCAT ('There are a total of ',count(OCCUPATION),' doctors.' )FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION='Doctor';

SELECT CONCAT ('There are a total of ',count(OCCUPATION),' singers.' )FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION='Singer';

SELECT CONCAT ('There are a total of ',count(OCCUPATION),' actors.' )FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION='Actor';

SELECT CONCAT ('There are a total of ',count(OCCUPATION),' professors.' )FROM OCCUPATIONS WHERE OCCUPATION='Professor';
```

Comment: Please note the comment M-Chen-3 placed on the original question. You need an explanation of how your code helps, not just the code.

Comment: Using all capitals is the internet equivalent of shouting, which makes it harder to read, and is also pretty rude. Please edit your answer to use normal capitalization.

Comment: @Tyler2P SQL requires certain keywords to be capitalized, though.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 The answer was not formatted in a code format and I am not yet familiar with SQL to recognize it.